# Configuring Session replication in Jboss EAP 6.2

Tags: configuration, server, jboss-eap-6, session-replication

Is it mandatory to use domain mode instead of standalone mode to enable session replication in Jboss EAP 6.2 ?

And can anyone provide a proper way to configure session replication in Jboss EAP 6.2 server?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use domain mode. You can use the `standalone-ha.xml` or `standalone-full-ha.xml` configuration profiles to enable session replication in multiple standalone environments. But the standalone instances need to be on the same subnet for this default configuration to work. Also you need to be sure the same version of your software is deployed to each environment - something that happens automatically in domain mode.

Your application also needs to be configured for session replication:

1) Add a `<distributable/>` tag in the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file.

2) In the load balancer (in front of the JBoss instances) enable sticky sessions so that individual users are assigned an JBoss instance, and directed back that same JBoss instance as long as that instance is available.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I had a bit investigation during past few days. I also figured out it's possible using standalone-ha.xml as you have said. But I got some errors in setting session variables in my application. Is it just enough to put <distributable/> tag or are there any other modifications to be done in the application ? thanks in advance